# Jax-Rs service is not getting invoked

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, tomcat7

I am developing JAX-RS Rest service using Apache CXF. After deploying it to Tomcat 7 server, if I type the URL `http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest?_wadl` it shows me the WADL. but if    I enter the URL `http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest/retrieve` it gives me 404 error.

In above URLs: `Rest` is the name of my project
`/rest` is the url-pattern for my `CXFServlet` which is specified in `web.xml`
`/` is the address of `jaxrs:server` which is specified in `beans.xml`
`retrieve` is the path of service which is specified in my interface with `@Path` annotation.

(My apologies: I can't provide the XML documents referred to above.)

Comment: Could you perhaps show your Java class? It seems to me that /retrieve is not matched. Do you have provided the method type?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a CXF bug which get the incorrect base URL for restful web services.

The class "org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController" invokes the method ["getBaseURL"](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http/2.6.2/org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/BaseUrlHelper.java#BaseUrlHelper.getBaseURL%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) of the class "org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.BaseUrlHelper".

It gets the base URL from request URL, and it ignores the parameters part.
This is correct for SOAP web servcies, because SOAP web services URL is just like: `http://host:port/basepath?para=a`. Unfortunately, for restful web services, the URL is just like `http://host:port/basepath/method/parameter`. The correct base URL should be `http://host:port/basepath`, but actually, the BaseUrlHelper gives you `http://host:port/basepath/method/parameter`. It just gives the URL before "?". It's why the result is correct when you access `http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest?_wadl`, in this case, it gives the correct base URL `http://localhost:8080/Rest`.

If you access `http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest?_wadl` at first then you access `http://localhost:8080/Rest/rest/retrieve`, it would be correct. Because, CXF set the base URL as the address of EndpointInfo only at the first time. It means, you MUST access the correct base URL at the first time! :(

The solution is: override the method ["getBaseURL(HttpServletRequest request)"](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http/2.6.2/org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/ServletController.java#ServletController.getBaseURL%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) of "org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController", let it return correct base URL.

For example, step1: extends the ServletController.

```
public class RestfulServletController extends ServletController {
    private final String basePath;

    public RestfulServletController(DestinationRegistry destinationRegistry, ServletConfig config,
            HttpServlet serviceListGenerator, String basePath) {
        super(destinationRegistry, config, serviceListGenerator);
        this.basePath = basePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBaseURL(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Fixed the bug of BaseUrlHelper.getBaseURL(request) for restful service.
        String reqPrefix = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        int idx = reqPrefix.indexOf(basePath);
        return reqPrefix.substring(0, idx + basePath.length());
    }
}
```

step2: extends CXFNonSpringServlet and use the RestfulServletController in the subclass

```
public class RestfulCXFServlet extends CXFNonSpringServlet {
    ... ...
    private ServletController createServletController(ServletConfig servletConfig) {
        HttpServlet serviceListGeneratorServlet = new ServiceListGeneratorServlet(destinationRegistry, bus);
        ServletController newController = new RestfulServletController(destinationRegistry, servletConfig,
            serviceListGeneratorServlet, basePath);
        return newController;
    }
}
```

step3: instead of CXFNonSpringServlet , you use the derived class RestfulServletController.
Don't forget, you should config the "basePath" as /Rest/rest.

Hope this can help you.